# Поиск совпадений по объектам массива

Tags: javascript

**Исходные данные:**

Есть массив contacts, каждый его элемент - это объект со своими свойствами. Нужно сделать функцию, которая берет значение `first` и сравнивает его со всеми `firstName` массива. Если совпадение есть, то нужно вывести второе заданное значение.

В конкретном случае это значение lastName того же объекта. Я уже и так, и эдак пытался, ничего не выходит.

Такое ощущение что `return contacts[i][prop];` просто не работает.

В результате должно вывести: "Vos"

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(first, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == first) {
      document.write('First name has matches<BR>')
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        document.write('Prop exist<BR>');
        return contacts[i][prop];
      }
      return "No such property";
      break;
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}

lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
document.write(lookUpProfile());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код работает. Просто вы теряете значение `Vos` и выполняете второй раз с пустыми значениями в этом месте:

```
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
document.write(lookUpProfile());
```

Поменяйте эти две строки на:

```
document.write(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(first, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == first) {
      document.write('First name has matches<BR>')
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        document.write('Prop exist<BR>');
        return contacts[i][prop];
      }
      return "No such property";
      break;
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}

document.write(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

К слову, можно чуть-чуть модифицировать ваш код с использованием [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example):

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(first, prop) {
  let contact = contacts.find(function(c) {
    return c.firstName === first;
  });
  if (!contact) {
    return "No such contact";
  }
  if (!contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    return "No such property";
  }

  return contact[prop];
}

document.write(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. В такой связке просто не выполнял код еще. 

Про "let" еще почитаю, все впереди.

А вот if с "И" не совпадает с условием задачи. Ведь нужно выводить 
"No such property" если свойства не существует.

Comment: @Amigo9876 вы про второй вариант? Я подправил.